# Taking the Average of multiple slider values

Tags: ios, swift, function, uislider

I am new to coding and need help pulling the value out of my slider functions. Right now I am trying to add two of the sender.values together by updating the outside variable in the slider function. I dont know how to pull the information out of the function. Anything helps! Thanks!

```
class sbBasicController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nutritionNum: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var hydrationNum: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var basicAvg: UILabel!


    // Variables

    private var nutritionValue: Float = 0.0
    private var hydrationValue: Float = 0.0


    //Functions

    @IBAction func nutritionScroll(_ sender: UISlider) {

        nutritionValue = sender.value

        nutritionNum.text = String(format: "%.1f", nutritionValue)
    }


    @IBAction func hydrationScroll(_ sender: UISlider) {

        hydrationValue = sender.value

        hydrationNum.text = String(format: "%.1f", hydrationValue)
    }


    func updateBasic() {

        let basics = (nutritionValue + hydrationValue)

        print("\(basics)")

        basicAvg.text = "\(basics)"
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is not working? You never actually call `updateBasic`. Do you need the average (you're not even doing averaging at the moment, just summing the two values) to be displayed whenever one of the two sliders change there value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply call the updateBasics function in both sliderNutrition& sliderHydration events.
declare the updateBasics function like this:

```
func updateBasics
{

hydrationNum.text = String(format: "%.1f", sliderHydration.value)

nutritionNum.text = String(format: "%.1f", sliderNutrition.value)

basicAvg.text =  sliderNutrition.value+ sliderHydration.value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now it doesn't appear like anything is calling `updateBasic()` which is why the `basicAvg` label isn't being updated

The `nutritionScroll` and `hydrationScroll` methods should each call `updateBasic()`.

```
@IBAction func nutritionScroll(_ sender: UISlider) {

    nutritionValue = sender.value

    nutritionNum.text = String(format: "%.1f", nutritionValue)

    updateBasic()
}
```

Another option would be to add a `didSet` to each of the `nutritionValue` and `hydrationValue` properties.

```
private var nutritionValue: Float = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        // You could even update nutritionNum.text here as well
        updateBasic()
    }
}
```